# Cloud Page - Save to Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I'm creating a custom profile page and I want to save some information in a custom object in Salesforce. How would I go about doing this? I assume I would be using SSJS rather than AMPscript. Thanks in advance, appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMPscript would definitely be the way to go, assuming you have [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm) configured. There are different AMPscript functions for creating and updating records in standard or custom objects.

### Create New Record

```js
var @createRecord
set @createRecord = CreateSalesforceObject(
      "MyCustomObjectApiName__c", 3,
      "field1__c", @field1,
      "field2__c", @field2,
      "field3__c", @field3
   )
```

### Update Existing Record

```js
var @updateRecord
set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
    "MyCustomObjectApiName__c", @Id,
    "field1__c", @field1,
    "field2__c", @field2,
    "field3__c", @field3
   )
```

Refer to [Sales and Service Cloud functions documentation](https://ampscript.guide/book/sales-and-service-cloud-functions/) for details on which arguments to use with these functions.

Answer (score 0):

@nicolevy try like this for creating new record in Custom object

```
%%[ 
  set @createrec=CreateSalesforceObject('customobject', 2, 'Field1', 'value1, 'field2', 'value2')

   ]%%
```